# Get string until first digit

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need to get all the characters before the first digit from an array.
I did this and it seems to work correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char temp[128] = {0};
    char str_active[128] = {0};

    sprintf(temp, "%s", "AB01");
    printf("Complete string.: %s\n", temp);

    int len = sizeof(temp) / sizeof(char);
    int index = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        if (isdigit(temp[index])) {
            break;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    snprintf(str_active, index + 1, "%s\n", temp);
    printf("String before first digit.: %s\n", str_active);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering if I could do the same with less instructions, so in a better way.

Comment: This is what I get: 

"Complete string.: AB01
String before first digit.: AB"

Comment: Use [`strcspn()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html) -- [see https://ideone.com/77chzf](https://ideone.com/77chzf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [strcspn](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn) can do it for you:

> The strcspn() function calculates the length of the initial segment of s which consists entirely of bytes not in reject.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char temp[128] = {0};
    char str_active[128] = {0};

    sprintf(temp, "%s", "AB01");
    printf("Complete string.: %s\n", temp);

    strncpy(str_active, temp, strcspn(temp, "0123456789"));
    printf("String before first digit.: %s\n", str_active);

    return 0;
}
```